# Call to undefined function imap_open() PHP 7 Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I am getting this error while

```
imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'username', 'password');
```

I have installed php imap extension by

```
 sudo apt-get install php7.0-imap
```

And also added an entry in php.ini file

```
extension=imap.so
```

Restarted apache2.4 server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

My php.ini file is located at /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini

But still I am getting the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Note: I had php5.6 but when i upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 it upgraded my system to PHP7. Earlier php.ini was loading from /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

**It worked after restarting my computer.**

Thanks

Comment: You enabled it in the wrong ini by the looks of it, `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` as the folders imply is the php.ini for the Command Line SAPI. Though I would normally have expected the apt-get to have enabled it for you.

Comment: @JonStirling in phpinfo It is showing this url only
    Loaded Configuration File /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini

Comment: You're getting that in phpinfo through your browser?

Comment: yes, i have added phpinfo() and tested it through browser

Comment: And it's pointed at the CLI php.ini? Then you've been doing some non-standard stuff in my opinion, making this rather difficult to try and answer.

Comment: @JonStirling I had php5.6 but when i upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 it upgraded my system to PHP7. Earlier it was loading from /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini